# I need xUnit test case of this. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos Container

Tags: unit-testing, azure-cosmosdb, xunit

I have use **Cosmosdb** Container its abstract class. 
I need **xUnit test** case with **mock** using **Moq library**

```
public class SmsTemplateRepository : ISmsTemplateRepository
{
    private Container _container;

    public SmsTemplateRepository(CosmosClient dbClient, string databaseName, string containerName) 
    {
        _container = dbClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);
    }

    public IEnumerable<SmsTemplate> GetAll()
    {
        return _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<SmsTemplate>(true);
    }

    **public async Task InsertAsync(SmsTemplate smsTemplate)
    {
        await _container.CreateItemAsync(smsTemplate);
    }**
}
```

Comment: Could you share what attempt have you done to mock the object and which is the failure or error you are getting?

Comment: No error i am not able to mock this method. public IEnumerable<SmsTemplate> GetAll()
    {
        return _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<SmsTemplate>(true);
    }

Comment: @DavinderSingh hi Davinder, were you able to solve this, do you have a working sample ? or can you mark an answer which worked for you ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to mock the whole chain from the dependency you pass into the constructor of the repository.

1. Create a list of templates you want to simulate GetAll to return:

```cs
var smsTemplates = new[]
{
  new SmsTemplate { Name = "Name1" },
  new SmsTemplate { Name = "Name3" }
}.AsQueryable()
 .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

2. Create a mocked CosmosClient and a mocked Container and setup the CosmosClient mock to return the mocked container:

```cs
var container = new Mock<Container>();
var client = new Mock<CosmosClient>();

client.Setup(x => x.GetContainer(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
      .Returns(container.Object);
```

3. Setup the mocked container to return the template list and pass in the mocked CosmosClient to the constructor of the repository:

```cs
container.Setup(x => x.GetItemLinqQueryable<SmsTemplate>(It.IsAny<bool>())
         .Returns(smsTemplates);
var repository = new SmsTemplateRepository(client.Object, ....);
```

4. GetAll will now return the smsTemplates

Comment: it gives me error (Can not convert List<model> to FeedResponse<model>) while putting List in Returns, do you know an alternative ?